# Studying the behaviour of a recursive formula with graph theory

Tags: number-theory, graph-theory

I have a recursive formula of the type :
$$
\begin{equation}
A_{r+1}(a)=\sum_{b \in X}A_{r}(b)\omega(a,b)
\end{equation}
$$
where $X$ is a set (vertices) and $\omega(a,b)$ is a COMPLEX weight such that :
$$
\begin{equation}
\sum_{b \in X}|\omega(a,b)|=1.
\end{equation}
$$
My work is studying the behaviour of $A_{k}(a))$ when $k$ goes to $+\infty$ and I wish to write
$$
\begin{equation}
A_{k}(r)=\pi(r)+O(2^{-kl}) 
\end{equation}
$$
for a certain $l$.
An idea consists in considering the matrice $M=(\omega(a,b))_{a,b \in X}$ and looking at the graph made by vertices. Do exist some conditions for the weights in order to apply ergodic theory (like a "Perron-Frobenius theorem")? Here, the graph I have is aperiodic, finite and irreductible, but as you understood, the weights are complex...